# Event Handler Send Mail Failing with SocketException

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, smtp, ssis-2016

I am working SQL Server 2016 and Visual Studio, but when I deployed my project to the Integration service catalog, SSIS send email task on event handler failed.

The error message as below:

> Error: an error occurred with the following error message: "failure sending mail. system.net.webexception: unable to connect to the remote server system.net.sockets.socketexception: an attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

I am using Gmail for this testing.

*SMTP SERVER: smtp.gmail.com*

[image: SMTP SERVER: smtp.gmail.com]

I've tried to turn off Windows Firewall and Anti-Virus and it still wont work.

```
The Package " + @[System::PackageName]  + " HAS FAILED"+ "
Package ID:" + @[System::PackageID] + "
Error Code:" + (DT_WSTR,50)@[System::ErrorCode] +"
Description:" +  @[System::ErrorDescription] + "
Error Source:" +  @[System::SourceName]
```

Will be send through email.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85172/Send-Email-from-SSIS-with-option-to-indicate-Email

Comment: http://umashanthan.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-send-email-notification-in-ssis.html

Comment: @Yahfoufi it wont work on event handler. I need to send the e-mail when the package failed to run.